# How to send a when only new record is added

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have a sample data like this

```
empid   ename   sal
-----------------------
1       raj      1000
2       somu    20000
```

When I run this query it will load in to table using SSIS or SQL Server and I need to send a mail either of using SEND MAIL TASK or `sp_dbsendmail` I will take care of that one.

The query will run every two hours through Job.

When it got loaded into table it will send mail in table format saying it have 2 records again after 2 hours it only have 2 records no need to sending mail and if it got any extra record need to send mail

```
    empid   ename   sal
    ---------------------
    1       raj      1000
    2       somu    20000
    3       Mohan    2000
```

The job will run for every 2 hours only send mail if it got new record otherwise no need to send ...Any ideas can you please suggest

Comment: add a datetime column called `processed`. When you email the records update the `processed` column of those that were emailed. On the next run test if there are any records with the `processed is null`

Comment: how i will check the condition Processed

Comment: ***WHAT*** query!?!? You talk about it - but you never **SHOW IT** to us!

Comment: show us wht you have tried.

Comment: it is simple query only i need to know how to send email along with previous records when new row added when it is not added how to restrict not to send email...job runs every two hours

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do this. Modify your table and add a new column:

```
ALTER TABLE employee ADD processed DATETIME NULL
```

This column will have a date/time of the last run

For your job to pickup the unprocessed records do this:

```
DECLARE @now DATETIME
SET @now = GetDate()

UPDATE employee SET processed = @now WHERE processed IS NULL

DECLARE @email VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @email = COALESCE(@email + '<br>', '') + 
                empid + ',' +  ename + ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), sal)
FROM employee
where processed = @now
order by empid

print email
--SEND mail
```

Comment: yeah i agree with this when i again ran after two hours i will check with isprocessed NULL but again i need to send cumulative email if it added new record otherwise i need not ...how i need to handle that condition

Comment: When a new record is added the processed column will be NULL for that record

Answer (score 0):

As cha suggested adding a date column in your table will hep you.

This code will the send query result in the body of your email.

If you want to be sent as an attachment please uncomment '**uncomment this!!!**' lines from the code.

```
-- count how many new records you have in the table based on date column
DECLARE @count AS int
SELECT @count = COUNT(empid) FROM MyTbl WHERE processed IS NULL

-- if you have new records -> send email otherwise no
IF @count > 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @subject varchar(50) = 'Your subject ... '
    DECLARE @Query varchar(max)
    DECLARE @recipients varchar(155)
    DECLARE @body varchar(155)
    --DECLARE @tab char(1) = CHAR(9) -- uncomment this!!!


    SET @recipients = 'email@co.uk'
    SET @body = 'bla bla ... ' + cast(@count as varchar) + ' new records have been added bla bla ... ' + CHAR(13)

    -- send email with all records available in table ... if you want only new ones add WHERE processed is NULL condition!
    SET @Query = CHAR(13) + 'SELECT empid, ename, sal, processed FROM MyTbl'


    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'YOUR PROFILE MAIL'
    ,@recipients = @recipients
    ,@subject = @subject
    ,@query = @Query
    ,@body = @body
    ,@execute_query_database = 'Your DB name'
    --,@attach_query_result_as_file = 1, -- uncomment this!!!
    --,@query_attachment_filename = 'filename.csv', -- uncomment this!!!
    --,@query_result_separator= @tab, -- uncomment this!!!
    --,@query_result_no_padding=1, -- uncomment this!!!
    --,@query_result_width=32767 -- uncomment this!!!
END

UPDATE MyTbl SET processed = GETDATE() WHERE processed IS NULL
```